# Replacing a string inside a a tag with a different string of text

Tags: jquery

I know this should be simple but I can't make it work. I have some text inside an  tag which I need to change. It's rendered by my CMS so I can't change it on the back end. Here is the html.

```
<a href="/OrderRetrievev2.aspx?CatalogueID=105038" class="cartSummaryLink">View Cart</a>
```

I need to change "View Cart" to "View Summary". Here is what I was trying to use with my jQuery.

```
    $'a.cartSummaryLink').text().replace("View Cart" , "View Summary");
```

It's not working. Thanks in advance for any help our suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it was just a copy-pase error, but you need to have an opening `(` on your `$()` function. Otherwise you will get a syntax error. Then, there is no need to call `.replace()`, `.text()` is a both a getter and a setter, so you can just pass `"View Summary"` to `.text()`, and it will change the element's text.

Like so:

```
$('a.cartSummaryLink').text("View Summary");
```

Answer (score 2):

.text() returns the text. .text(val) replaces the text.

```
$('a.cartSummaryLink').text("View Summary");
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, let's say there was other text in the link, but you only want to replace View Cart to become View Summary.  You can try something like this..

```
var link = $('a.cartSummaryLink');
var linkText = link.text();
link.text( linkText.replace("View Cart", "View Summary") );
```

This makes use of the .text() function from jQuery, but the String manipulation function available from Javascript.

Hope it helps!